# PHP not Getting Params From $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

first time posting and its because it have no more ideas why this is,
i have the following code

**HTML**

```
<div> <p> <font face='Verdana, Tahoma, Arial' size='3'> <b> Subir Archivo </b></font> </p>
<!--Formulario para elejir el archivo a subir -->
<form action='' method='post' name='form_ftp' id='form_ftp' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<font size='2' face='Verdana, Tahoma, Arial'> Elegir archivo :<br>
<div> <input name='archivo' onchange='myApp.fileCheck(this)' class='btn btn-info btn-xs' id='files' type='file' style='padding:2px; font-size:12px; width: 275px' /> </div><br><br>
<input type='hidden' name='opt' value='$id'>
<input name='submit' type='hidden' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' id='path' name='path'>
<input id='subir' onclick='myApp.uploadIt()' type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-xs' value='Subir Archivo' style='display:none;padding:2px; font-size:12px; width: 90px;' /> </font> </form> </div>
```

**JS**

```
uploadIt:function(){

        $('#cargando').show();
        $('#path').val(myApp.rPath);
        var formData = new FormData($('#form_ftp')[0]);
        $.ajax( {            
            url: './controllers/ftp/ftpController.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        }).done(function(){
//            $("#files").val('');
//            myApp.getData();
        });

    },
```

Ok this is good its working pics of that now
Params File Passing at last

[image: Params]

Now checking the php Code its empty nothing it's passed

**PHP** codes i used to check its a var dump

```
var_dump($_POST,$_GET,$_FILES,$_REQUEST);
```

to see the var dumps params

varDump

[image: varDump]

the response its giving me its the else, that's mean there is nothing that to do, no post or get of any kind but the params are passed. why this is happening

Comment: Can you check what is in "formData" please ? `console.log(formData)` just after `var formData = new FormData($('#form_ftp')[0]);`

Comment: Have you tried removing `processData:false,` to see if it comes through then?

Comment: didnt work eaither that tht javascript broke if i remove that options,

Comment: can you post the code associated to the if else statement?

Answer (score 0):

You need read the request body: `file_get_contents( 'php://input', 'r' );`

Comment: if i use that method how i can get the file data, its give me string only i checked php manuals and there arent a wise advise. also i have some more params on the form that are in bottom if u see the html code are input type hidden.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

Updated.

```
  var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("form_ftp"));
  $.ajax({
    url: './controllers/ftp/ftpController.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    processData: false, 
    contentType: false,
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
        //Do something on error
        console.log(error);
    },
    success:function(data){
        //Do something on success
        console.log(data); //Response data
    }
  });
```

Comment: if i serialize the form the file wont go trough the post, thats why i do the form data like i did it, i faced that problem before

Comment: Still Empty. nothing. this is kidding me, its give me the response of success data, the else statement of the php code

Comment: at the top of your php script write `var_dump($_POST); exit;`. are the values passed shown in your console?

Comment: i did that i can show u the whle php document ant they are empty. post . request. get and file are empty.  C:\wamp\www\gestionTal\controllers\ftp\ftpController.php:32:
array (size=0)
  empty

C:\wamp\www\gestionTal\controllers\ftp\ftpController.php:32:
array (size=0)
  empty

C:\wamp\www\gestionTal\controllers\ftp\ftpController.php:32:
array (size=0)
  empty

C:\wamp\www\gestionTal\controllers\ftp\ftpController.php:32:
array (size=0)
  empty
the response for var_dump

Comment: line 32 its before some checking if the user can do the actions and controllin the session also including files so its the first affter all the controls before user can do anything